# Question involving integration of nonnegative measurable functions using simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, simple-functions

Question: I am working on a problem in Folland's Real Analysis (specifically, 2.16) and I want to justify something:
Suppose $f$ is a measurable nonnegative function and $\int f<\infty$.  Let $\epsilon >0$.  Then, there exists simple function $\phi=\sum_n a_n\chi_{E_n}$ such that $0\leq \phi\leq f$.  So, by monotonicity, I can say $\int\phi \leq \int f$.  It would be terrific if I could then say that for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $(\int f)-\epsilon<\int\phi$ (note that all integrals so far are taken over our general measurable set $X$). But, can I say this?  What if $\epsilon$ is REALLY small.. then how can I essentially "flip" the integral $\int\phi\leq \int f$ when subtracting $\epsilon$ from the RHS?

Comment: $\phi$ depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah, do you mean that I can only say this if I choose $\phi$ to be, the simple function such that this is true?  And, I know such a $\phi$ exists, because I can just pull out an appropriate one from the sequence of simple functions $\psi_n$ of simple functions such that $0\leq\psi_1\leq\cdots \leq f$ where $\psi_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise, right?  I suppose I am still "concerned" because I can't think of WHY such a $\phi$ would exist... what if all the $\psi_j$ are REALLY close to $f$?